# Javascript object prototype arrow function not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

I thought this would be really simple but it's not working for some reason. I want to make a dot function to check for multiple object properties:

```js
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperties = (properties) => { return properties.every(prop => this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) }

var test = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'boz'
}

result = test.hasOwnProperties(['foo', 'baz'])
console.log(result)
```

I expected it to return `true` since `test` contains both `foo` and `baz` but it returns `false`. Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You must not use arrow functions (`=>`) when working with `prototype`s and referencing their instances (i.e. `this`) because arrow functions are lexically scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperties = function(properties) { return properties.every(prop => this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) }

var test = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'boz'
}

result = test.hasOwnProperties(['foo', 'baz'])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: My beautiful arrows :(